# Specified record in top of results list

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

Task: selecting specified record in top of results list

my ugly variant:

```
(select * from mytable where id = 42)
union all
(select * from mytable where id != 42 order by id)
```

besides of `ansi` query variant for `mysql` is also would be very interesting to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between ANSI and vendor SQL solutions

```
select *
from mytable 
order by
    CASE WHEN id = 42 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id
```

Note: there is **no** guaranteed or implied order to a table or SELECT without an ORDER BY clause

Comment: When I started writing my answer I'm pretty sure you were editing yours and adding second part; anyway you were first (upvoted), so do you prefer me to delete my answer? Thanks

Comment: about first query: why so strange ordering rules `0, -n, ..., +m` ?

Comment: @Marco: delete if you want, but there was no overlap

Comment: @gbn how about `ansi` (i'm interesting for both optimal variants)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming id is always positive, try:

```
select *
from mytable 
order by CASE WHEN id = 42 THEN 0 ELSE id END
```

Comment: Tanks. Though in my example I've selected by PK but most common query is preferable to me